# User generated reports from mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine a form that has  these fields:

```
select: 

From:

where:
```

A user would enter what they want to select, from where, and the conditional. This form would go to a model that may (probably not :D) look like this:(using jquery datatables here)

```
 public function custom_report($input)
{
    $this->datatables->select($input['select']);
    if( ! empty($input['where'])){
        $this->datatables->where($input['where']);
       }

    $this->datatables->join($this->$input['join']. ' AS ' . $input['as'] .',  '.$input['join_clause']);

    $this->datatables->from($input['from']);

    $this->datatables->add_column('actions', '');

    $data = $this->datatables->generate();

    return $data;
}
```

The idea is to have someone be able to field those input fields with the column headings they want to return. How would any statement that required joins or multiple joins work here?

Comment: it looks like you are attempting to put a front end form on a ORM query generator.  just map the ORM methods faithfully

Comment: To be honest: I've not idea what you mean about this. Googling

Comment: You are talking about self service reporting more than a ORM here.